# How do I allow a user to replace a number with a character - Tic-Tac-Toe C++

Tags: c++, arrays, io

I am building a tic-tac-toe game and the table is displayed with numbers as place-holders for the characters `X` and `O`.  I have no idea how to allow a user to select a number, and replace it with an `X` or `O`.  I understand `cin >>`, but don't know how to use it in this scenario.

This is a very introductory program, and is for my programming class.  I'm not asking for someone to code it for me, but I have no clue where to begin in doing this.  If you can help, please keep it as beginner-oriented as possible, otherwise I won't be able to implement it into my program because it will look fishy.

This is my code as of now:

```
using namespace std;

int board[9] {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
};

void displayBoard(void) {
char index;
    cout << endl;
    cout << board[index] << "|" << board[index+1] << "|" << board[index+2] << endl;
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    cout << board[index+3] << "|" << board[index+4] << "|" << board[index+5] << endl;
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    cout << board[index+6] << "|" << board[index+7] << "|" << board[index+8] << endl;
    index = index + 9;
        cin >> board[index];


}

void playerInput(void) {

}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    displayBoard();


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better choice could be to display the board using an array of type **char**. And you can always convert the characters to integers, or use board's index if you need to use them for calculations(which I doubt you will have to).

```
 char board[9] {
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
    };
```

if you need access to those integer values just use the board's index+1.

You can use this:

```
cin >> movePosition;
```

to accept user's input. and when you need to edit the board just use:

```
   board[movePosition-1] = 'X';
```

or

```
   board[movePosition-1] = 'O';
```

This will now work as the array is of type **char**.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a huge help..  Now, the program runs - and I played around with it to get it to input the X rather than the number, but it won't update the array.

http://pastebin.com/r3zj6PWE

That's what I have as of now.

Comment: use the same cin I used in my answer, that should work.

Comment: Thank you, Nassim!!  Both of you guys really helped shed some light on this for me.  I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The **ASCII** values of 1 through nine is 48 to onward. Use that values in the board. Print using
`cout<<(char)board[index];` When user enters a position, place `X` or `O` character in that index according to the player and display the board again.

```
int board[9] {
  48, 49..
};

cout<<(char) board[index];
```